# Don't repeat random numbers in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a code below that is doing animations on a random element between 1 and 6. But here it repeats one number x amounts of times.

How can I change this code to not repeat a random number?

```
x = 6;
$("#best_brands > .flow > img").each(function() {

    var timer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 600
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
    fadeBrands(timer, number); 

});

function fadeBrands(timer, number) {

        $('#best_brands > .flow > img:lt("'+number+'")').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, timer);  

}
```

Comment: Will the animation repeat or is it a one time thing for all 6?

Comment: No, it should be able to repeat

Answer (score 4):

Please read Matt's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045615/javascript-generate-random-unique-number-every-time):

```
var grabBag = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// randomize order of elements with a sort function that randomly returns -1/0/1
grabBag.sort(function(xx,yy){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1; })

function getNextRandom(){
    return grabBag.shift();
};

var originalLength = grabBag.length;
for(var i = 0; i < originalLength .length; i++){
    console.log(getNextRandom());
}
```

Also may consider reading this question: [Unique Random Number Generator Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584716/unique-random-number-generator-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way of doing the same: 
every time you get a random number you can store it in `usedNumbers` array and check if the next random number is already present `usedNumbers` array every time.