# How to create 3 unique values from an array of characters

Tags: javascript

can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can  create 3 unique values from an array of numbers?

```js
var num = [];
var chances = "0123456789";
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  num.push(chances.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chances.length)));
}

console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not just `Math.floor((Math.random() * 10))` and as the values are _random_, that doesn't mean it should be **unique**, especially when creating a single-digit random value

Comment: Hi Tushar I already tried it but was n't sure how o limit the number of selected item to 3?!

Comment: Do you want three unique characters from your string with no repeats?  What you have is not actually an array of characters - it's a string.

Comment: Unique randoms here: [unique random array javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399740/unique-random-array-javascript/22400087#22400087) and [Generating random numbers on different input texts and ensuring random numbers shown are unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401012/generating-random-numbers-on-different-input-texts-and-ensuring-random-numbers-s/23401087#23401087) and [Javascript generate random unique number every time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045615/javascript-generate-random-unique-number-every-time/7046877#7046877).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
var num = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3;) {
  var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  //  You can generate random number between 0-9 using this , suggested by @Tushar
  if (num.indexOf(ran) == -1)
  // check number is already in array
    num[i++] = ran;
    // if not then push the value and increment i
}

document.write(num.join());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For getting unique alphabets

```js
var res = [],
  alp = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
  // creating an array of alphabets for picking alphabers
for (var i = 0; i < 3;) {
  var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  //  You can generate random number between 0-25 using this
  if (res.indexOf(alp[ran]) == -1)
  // check alphabet is already in array
    res[i++] = alp[ran];
  // if not then push the value and increment i
}

document.write(res.join());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or

```js
var res = [],
  alp = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
  // creating an array of alphabets for picking alphabers
for (var i = 0; i < 3;) {
  var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) % 26;
  //  You can generate random number between 0-25 using this
  if (res.indexOf(alp[ran]) == -1)
  // check alphabet is already in array
    res[i++] = alp[ran];
  // if not then push the value and increment i
}

document.write(res.join());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav C Balan, can you also let me know hoe to get 3 unique letter from alphabet as well?

Comment: That's a nice work-around @Behseini but keep in mind `this does not generate random unique numbers, this'll just pick unique numbers from random numbers`

Comment: @Behseini You cannot generate random numbers that are unique.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are saying now

Comment: @Behseini : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this code:

```js
var num = [];
var chances = "0123456789";
var len = chances.length;
var str;
while (num.length < 3) {
  str = "";
  while (str.length < len)
    str += chances[Math.floor((Math.random() * len) % len)];
  if (-1 === num.indexOf(str))
    num.push(str);
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(num));
```